# How to do Paypal Parallel payments with Expresscheckout?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Am looking into the Paypal parallel payments with express checkout.
I have tried it but failed , Am looking for a sample code so that i can easy to understand and work on it. Thanks friends Am very much Appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you working with PHP?  If so, you can use this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/).  It has the Express Checkout calls setup for you and you can pass in multiple $Payment data arrays so that it handles the parallel payment for you.

Comment: Yes am using PHP and i have the done the express checkout with parallel payment. Now am stuck with a token login.

User signup with PayPal into my site. PayPal returns all user data including the identity token.
By using that identity token am calling seamless checkout so that user don't need to login again in PayPal payment gateway for transferring money.now the problem is Identity token expiring in particular period of time. if the token expired it asking user to login when trasferring money.